# Android getView : Why getView not called?

Tags: android, android-adapter

I add two buttons (add and delete) to control the list view, when I delete an item, the item won't immediately disappear in the listview, only when I slide on the listview, the new item disappears. The getView() in my adapter won't be called after I delete an item unless I touch the screen or slide on the listview. can someone tell me why?

My xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/locationlist_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >"

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/locationlisttitle_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:background="#ADD8E6">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_menu2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_menu" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtv_locationmanagetitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Manage Location List"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_addlocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtv_locationmanagetitle"
            android:src="@drawable/addlocation" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_deletelocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_addlocation"
            android:src="@drawable/deletelocation" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_locations"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My button click event handler

```
ivbtn_deleteLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //remove selected items from the locationList
            Collections.sort(listStr);
            for (int i = listStr.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                Log.i("zhijianw", "remove"+listStr.get(i));
                Log.i("zhijianw", "remove"+locationList.get(Integer.parseInt(listStr.get(i))).get("txtv_locationitem"));
                String remLocation = locationList.get(Integer.parseInt(listStr.get(i))).get("txtv_locationitem").toString();
                locationList.remove(Integer.parseInt(listStr.get(i)));
                removeLocation(remLocation);
            } 
            listStr = new ArrayList<String>();
            locationsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
});
```

My Adapter

```
  public MyAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, Object>> list, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
            this.context = context;
            this.list = list;
            keyString = new String[from.length];
            idValue = new int[to.length];
            System.arraycopy(from, 0, keyString, 0, from.length);
            System.arraycopy(to, 0, idValue, 0, to.length);
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            init();
            Log.i("zhijianw", "my adapter called"); 
    }

    public void init() {
            isSelected = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    isSelected.put(i, false);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.i("zhijianw", "get count called");  
            return list.size(); 
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        Log.i("zhijianw", "get item called");
            return list.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {
        init();
        Log.i("zhijianw", "get view called");           
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (view == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_item, null);
                holder.tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtv_locationitem);
                holder.cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_locationitem);
                view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        HashMap<String, Object> map = list.get(position);
        if (map != null) {
                itemString = (String) map.get(keyString[0]);
                holder.tv.setText(itemString);
        }
        holder.cb.setChecked(isSelected.get(position));
        return view;
    }

}
```

Set listview adapter

```
lv_menu = (ListView) menu_view.findViewById(R.id.lv_menu);
lv_menu.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_item,   R.id.txtv_menuItem, menuChoices));
```

Comment: @NullPointer But I need to override getView() to set the TextView and CheckBox in my list_item. I set a breakpoint in the getView function, it won't be called until I silde the listView. If I slide on the listview, the getView will be immediately called, and the item will be deleted.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Not able to find out the solution. Can you please anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

The `locationsAdapter` does not appear to be getting set to the same adapter used by `lv_menu.setAdapter()` so that `locationsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is not invalidating `lv_menu`. Try `lv_menu.invalidate()` directly in your `onClick()` function.

I personally reload my list adapters from scratch whenever deleting items, especially when `CheckBox` items are involved, in order to keep things from getting out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the parameter transfered to the inflater (in the getView method) refer to the same parameter which was used when the adapter was intiated. In the case that they are not the same the getView will not be called without any further notification.
Zohar